# Update an Int inside a function to global

Tags: scala, function

I'm a beginner in Scala and I'm having some trouble writing code for a game which involves moving around a 2D array.

```
class Game(
  wall: List[(Int, Int)], 
  bounty: List[(Int, Int, Int => Int)], 
  var playerX: Int, 
  var playerY: Int
)
```

Here I initialise my `playerX` and `playerY` values.

```
def getPlayerPos(): (Int, Int) = {
  return (playerX, playerY);
}
```

Here the function `getPlayerPos()` is to update the original `playerX` and `playerY`

```
def al() {
  if (playerX - 1 >= 0)
    if (field(playerX - 1)(playerY) == true) {
      if (!wall.contains(playerX - 1, playerY))
        playerX - 1
      checkBounty();
      checkBounties();
      getPlayerPos();
    }
}
```

This code 'should' move the player to the left, yet the `playerX` and `playerY` always reset to 0 after moving once.

Have I missed something important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that you are missing an assignment for `playerX`:

```
if (!wall.contains(playerX - 1,playerY)) {
  playerX = playerX - 1
}
```

You also do not need (and should not have) the `return` in `getPlayerPos`:

```
def playerPos: (Int, Int) = (playerX, playerY)
```

You also discard the result of this call, but I suspect that is because this is only a code fragment and not real code.

More generally, you should look at implementing this in a more functional style. So rather than modifying the board at each step, the functional approach is to create a new board at each step based on the old board and the user inputs. This may seem expensive, but it does simplify the logic which will make things easier as the game gets more complicated.